# ReactJS/JavaScript RegExr Converting data of object html into text

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

How can I convert in JavaScript/ReactJS into string.
For example I have an object:

```
{
  article: '<p class="md-block-unstyled">First text...</p><p>Second text></p>'
}
```

I want to convert it and render a paragraph:

`First Text... Second text`

I don't want the `<p>` tag or any others tag to be printed on the screen but I want them to behave as actual paragraphs.

Comment: Please phrase your question correctly. What is the structure of your object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render HTML from a string.

**Example**

```js
function App() {
  const obj = {
    article: '<p class="md-block-unstyled">First text...</p><p>Second text</p>'
  };
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: obj.article }} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! But I would like to do it without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. There is no other option to do it ?

Comment: @DgenVnk `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the React way of doing it, but you should only do it if you trust the HTML in the string and you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.

```
const obj = {
  article: '<p class="md-block-unstyled">First text...</p><p>Second text></p>'
} 


<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: obj.article}} />
```